# Special character in URL on IIS, IIS hanging

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, sitecore, windows-server-2008-r2, freeze

I have tumbled with a problem with IIS on the Windows Server 2008 R2 for some time now. I have a website that needs to be moved to this server.

What happend when we move the solution is that every URL that have special character as æ, ø, å, á or spaces (%20) etc. will not work, hanging and lastly times out. The problem occours both on images and files (ashx, gif, jpg). Everything looks like it's being URL encoded.

We have no issue at all on the old server on this matter.

Here is some example of the issue:

- http://biva-search.workingpropeople.com/~/media/Flash%20-%20og%20alternativer%20740x188/TLFlash/Timberman.ashx?w=740&h=231
- http://biva-search.workingpropeople.com/~/media/170x120/Boerne_t%C3%A6pper.ashx?mw=170

I'm sure it is some crazy settings I missed out and I hope someone here can help me out :)

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the IIS issue/solution, afaik special characters are not allowed in URLs, but the "Sitecore" way of resolving this is character replacement via config. This article explains config change required: [SEO-friendly URLs in Sitecore](http://blog.navigationarts.com/seo-url-sitecore/)

But essentially you need to add more encodenamereplacements in Sitecore config:

```
<encodenamereplacements>
    ...
    <replace mode="on" find="æ" replaceWith="a" />
    <replace mode="on" find="ø" replaceWith="o" />
</encodenamereplacements>
```

There is another thread with a similar issue: [Sitecore issue on replacing danish characters in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226540/sitecore-issue-on-replacing-danish-characters-in-url)

Comment: We try that out. But if we add the characters to encodenamereplacements, will it then also affects the folders and filenames? As I can see it, Sitecore have build the folders with spaces and that of course is shown in the URL.

Comment: It will affect the URL, that's the whole point - to replace one character with another. If you want to replace the spaces then add in

<replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-" />

But be aware in this case that you should not allow hyphens (-) in the names to begin with otherwise Sitecore will transform hyphens back in to spaces when resolving the item which will cause it not to be found. It depends in your overall requirements and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please see my answer in the thread linked by jammykam on the problems with replacing Danish special characters, it isn't possible to simply replace "æ" with "a".

Comment: The SC LinkManager now includes a `lowercaseUrls="true"` so you no longer need to worry about uppercase transforms yourself. Good point on the double characters, and as you say the best solution is to rename the items and use the display name for the editor.