# web.config redirect for Æ to O

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config, umbraco8

I just updated my website, and now my old and new urls doesn't match. The problem is that i uses Æ in my urls. The old site converted Æ to OE but the new site is converting Æ to O.

Therefore i have a lot of urls on google that does not work. I tried to make a redirect in my web.config but cant get it to work.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="oe to e" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)oe(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}o{R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: Is there any difference between the configuration of your two sites? Please ensure that the ApplicationPool.ManagedPipelineMode Property of the 2 sites is the same in applicationPool advanced settings.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802795/8291949